# Prevent templated copy constructor from being called

Tags: c++, templates

In the following, the templated copy constructor is being called.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A
{
public:
    A(){ cout << "Class A constructor\n";}
    A(const A &a){ cout << "Class A copy constructor\n"; }
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    B(){ cout << "Class B constructor\n";}
    B(const B &a){ cout << "Class B copy constructor\n"; }
};

template <typename T>
class Template
{
public:
    Template() { cout << "Template default\n"; }
    Template(const Template &a) { cout << "Template copy constructor\n"; }

    // This gets called
    template <typename T2>
    Template(const Template<T2> &a)
    {
        cout << "Templated template copy constructor\n";
    }

};

void funcT(const Template<A> &a)
{
}

int main()
{
    Template<B> bt;

    cout << "Calling funcT(bt)\n";
    funcT(bt);

    return 0;
}
```

How can I prevent the templated copy constructor from being called?  I was expecting that since `B` is of type `A`, and I'm passing by reference, no constructor would not get called.  I created a specialized copy constructor in hopes it would get called instead:

```
Template(const Template<A> &a)
{
    cout << "Specialized templated template copy constructor\n";
}
```

But that does not compile.

Basically, I don't want to call the existing three constructors when I call `funcT()`.

Comment: does making it `explicit` is what you need [like in this demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7e8a2096add35e7e) ?

Comment: `Template<B> != Template<A>` dude, that's why the templated conversion constructor is called.

Comment: Please notice: A template constructor is never (!) a copy constructor

Comment: Ok, that makes sense.  Is the only option to create a specialized template class for A?

Comment: @user2233706: make the constructor `explicit`, or remove the templated constructor and instead provide `explicit operator Template<T2>()`, or add `enable_if` condition to your constructor

Comment: It's the one way to call `funcT`, which takes as input argument a `Template<A>` object, with an input object of type `Template<B>`. Somehow  `bt` must be converted to `Template<A>` for `funcT` call to work.

Comment: @Pior S. Thanks, I didn't know such a site existed.  Using `explicit` prevents the templated constructor from being called, but I was looking for a way to pass the `bt` to `funcT()` without calling any of the three constructors and have the code compile.  I'll clarify this in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make your function a template that accepts any `Template<T>` **but only when** `T` inherits from `A`, so that no copies/conversions are made:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
auto funcT(const Template<T>& a)
    -> typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<A, T>::value>::type
{
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fda292ab3a918465)

---

> *We are not using C++0x*

You can write your own `enable_if` and `is_base_of`:

```
template <bool b, typename T = void>
struct my_enable_if {};
template <typename T>
struct my_enable_if<true, T> { typedef T type; };
template <typename Base, typename Derived>
struct my_is_base_of
{
    static char test(Base*);    
    static long test(...);
    static const bool value = sizeof(test((Derived*)0)) == sizeof(char);
};

template <typename T>
typename my_enable_if<my_is_base_of<A, T>::value>::type funcT(const Template<T>& a)
{
}
```

[**C++98 DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6519721641d49924)

Comment: @user2233706: `enable_if` and `is_base_of` are easily portable to C++98, the `auto` is not needed at all, just to have sfinae in a trailing part

Comment: robert's answer also works.  What advantages does this answer have versus robert's?

Comment: @user2233706: you have additional constraint here so that this function works only when `T` is derived from `A`. I assume this is what you wanted, hence you provided `class A` and `class B : public A` hoping the `funcT(Template<A>)` would work with `funcT(Template<B>)`

Comment: robert's solution also works with either `funcT(Template<A>)` or `funcT(Template<B>)`.  Not saying one solution is better than the other, but trying to see what are the advantages of one solution over the other.

Comment: @user2233706 it all depends on what you want, I added the constraint on purpose hoping you *do want* this to work **only** with template arguments derived from `A`. Robert's solution will work even with `Template<int>` and literally anything.

Answer (score 1):

Just because B derives from A does not mean `Template<B>` derives from `Template<A>`. Depending on what you're trying to accomplish a template function may work:

```
template<typename T>void funcT(const Template<T> &a)
{
}
```

> ./a.out
>   Template default
>   Calling funcT(bt)

Robert